# How to make userfield to be ignore duplicate values

Tags: php, html, mysql

IS there any way through which when an user enter data into html form field can get error if values are same
Like i want to make a field that can show error if any field like username and email field already exist in database
in simple word I want to make a field of html which can shows error if data is already exist into database

Comment: Post your attempt here.

Comment: Yes, post your attemp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```mysql
INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = col1;
```